# redis-server not working if port is changed

Tags: php, wordpress, redis

`sudo systemctl status redis-server.service`
its ok

redis active en other port example 30000
but

redis-server --port 30000

> oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
>   5315:C 24 Aug 00:07:42.719 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=5315, just started
>   5315:C 24 Aug 00:07:42.719 # Configuration loaded
>   5315:M 24 Aug 00:07:42.720 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:30000: bind: Address already in use

use 
`ps aux | grep redis`
and them kill -9 process

and then 
`redis-server --port 30000` 
but iqual

Comment: Are there any other services running on `30000` instead of redis?

Comment: only redis but redis-cli -p 30000  is very good

Answer (score 0):

Check port 30000 is not blocked by your firewall. If your redis is start on cloud, check port 30000 is added in your security group.

Comment: hello if it's added to the firewall

Comment: hello finally I had to delete the server.
install php7.3 redis-server and now if all good install wordpress and the Redis Object Cache extension and wordpress. I want to install redisearch but
restarting redis-server doesn't let me     what is the correct way to restart redis-server in ubuntu 18 with another port